Public signing cert for simplesaml
I am trying to config simplesamlphp to test my saml client which uses passport js.  Passport saml requires a certificate to be set.  However when trying to setup simplesaml w/ a cert I am getting an error.
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="test">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://test.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://test.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>

This is the test cert that is provided by the docker container I am running here:
https://github.com/kristophjunge/docker-test-saml-idp
Settings in authsources.php according to the docs (https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp.html):
'default-sp' => [
    'saml:SP',
    'entityID' => 'https://myapp.example.org/',
    'privatekey' => 'server.pem',
    'certificate' => 'server.crt',
],

Using passportjs, I am providing the cert:
passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
  {
    path: '/saml/callback',
    entryPoint: ...,
    issuer: 'passport-saml',
    cert: 'server.crt',
  },

Any idea what I am doing wrong with respect to configuration?

are you configuring your simplesamlphp as sp or IDP ?

Here is example how to setup passport-saml at express application when IdP that you use is the one you refer to and when it is configured the way it is.
Actual answer is at following javascript code (see how passport-saml is configured).
In order to run following example follow the steps written to it.
//
// First few words of warning for those who use copy paste coding
// from stackoverflow:
//
// This example is NOT suitable for any production purposes.
//
// This is just an example answer to stackoverflow question
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78437400/public-signing-cert-for-simplesaml
// and ONLY purpose is to demonstrate setting up authentication part of the SAML2.0
//
// This example skips for example problems with single logout see:
// https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/issues/419
//
// furthermore this example code skips among other things in response to
// validation, idp issuer validation, saml error response handling,
// signing messages sent by SP, using encrypted assertions, etc etc
//
// DO NOT use this source code at production
//
// DO NOT copy paste code from this to production
// if you have no clue whatsoever how weak following setup is

//
// Step 1
//
// Instead of setting up test IdP like this:
// https://github.com/kristophjunge/docker-test-saml-idp/blob/v1.15.2-1/README.md#usage
// lets setup it up like this in order to be able use express application at port >1024
// i.e. setting SP's (express application with passport saml) port to 8181 into
// "SP metadata provisioned to IdP". NOTE: this modification is done only
// in order to be able to run this test scenario without root privileges (normal
// user doesn't usually have privileges to open services to ports < 1024 )
// 
// i.e. first launch IdP like this:
// only difference to linked example is that there is now port 8181 instead of
// default http port (at SP metadata that is configured to IdP in this particular
// case via those three environment variables)
/*

docker run --name=testsamlidp_idp \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-e SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ENTITY_ID=http://app.example.com \
-e SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE=http://localhost:8181/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/test-sp \
-e SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_SINGLE_LOGOUT_SERVICE=http://localhost:8181/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/test-sp \
-d kristophjunge/test-saml-idp

*/


// Step 2
//
// create directory and place following
// package.json
// to it
/*

{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@node-saml/passport-saml": "^5.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0"
  }
}

*/

// Step 3
//
// run
/*

npm install

*/

// Step 4
//
// create index.js file with following content:

//
// This part of the code is just dummy test code in order
// to provide you something runnable. Actual SO question answer
// is written to the part of this JS code that configures
// passport-saml
//
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const SamlStrategy = require("@node-saml/passport-saml").Strategy;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  encoded: true,
  extended: true,
}));
app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: "secret_used_to_sign_cookie",
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      // because using http for this example:
      secure: false
    }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.serializeUser( function(user, done) { done(null, user); } );
passport.deserializeUser( function(user, done) { done(null, user); } );
//
// Start of the answer to your question
//
passport.use(new SamlStrategy({
    // callback URL (path) must be same that was provisioned to IdP for this
    // SP (and in this case at SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE )
    // (normally this provision would be done with SP metadata or via some other
    // more sophisticated method)
    callbackUrl: "/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/test-sp",
    // this must point to your IdP's SingleSingOnService endpoint
    // see IdP metadata from:
    // http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php
    entryPoint: "http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php",
    // this must match with whats being provisioned to IdP
    // in this particular case you have provisioned value at SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_ENTITY_ID
    // (normally this provision would be done with SP metadata or via some other
    // more sophisticated method)
    issuer: "http://app.example.com",
    // NOTE: starting from @node-saml/passport-saml 5.0.0 "cert" is "idpCert"
    //
    // "signing" certificate from IdP metadata:
    // http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php
    idpCert: "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",
    // defaults to value of issuer but provided it
    // explicitily because it (issuer) was incorrect
    // at SO question (didn't match with what was configured
    // for this SP to IdP side)
    audience: "http://app.example.com",
}, function(profile, done) { done(null, profile) }));
//
// End of the answer to your question
//
app.get("/login", passport.authenticate("saml", {} ));

// this is callbackUrl:
app.post("/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/test-sp",
  passport.authenticate("saml", {}), function(req, res){res.redirect("/")}
);

// read https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/issues/419
// to understand single logout problems
// at this particular case SP's single logout endpoint that
// was provisioned to IdP is following (same as SIMPLESAMLPHP_SP_SINGLE_LOGOUT_SERVICE )
//
// NOTE: this endpoint CANNOT be used to trigger logout process
//       this endpoint would consume LogoutRequest messages that
//       are triggered by IdP when it propagates logout requests
//       to single sign on session participants when some other SP
//       has initiated single logout process
//
//       if you want to implement logout process you must have
//       in addition to this an endpoint like /logout and when user clicks
//       it this SP must send LogoutRequest to IdP (in addition to
//       performing local logout prior to triggering SLO process)
app.post("/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/test-sp", passport.authenticate("saml", {} ));

// this endpoint is used to test whether user has authenticated session or not
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.send("<html><body><pre>hello \n" + JSON.stringify(req.user, null, 2) + "</pre></body></html>");
    } else {
        res.send('<html><body><p>Access denied. <a href="/login">[LOGIN]</a></p></body></html>');
    }
});

// NOTE: didn't introduce SP side logout initiator endpoint on purpose
// so that copy paste coders must take some time to understand how SAML 2.0
// works (instead of just copy pasting code from above)

app.listen(8181, () => { console.log("Listening at port 8181")})

// Step 5
//
// launch program with:
/*

node index.js

*/

// Step 6
//
// go with your browser to:
// http://localhost:8181/
//
// click login and you'll be redirected to IdP launched at step 1
//
// login with "user1" "user1pass"
//
// and you'll be redirected back and in case of successfull authentication
// information stored to "reg.user" is printed
// example output when signed in with user1:
/*

hello 
{
  "issuer": "http://localhost:8080/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php",
  "inResponseTo": "_eade7b82613132b143e48de5421c772a0f0328f6",
  "sessionIndex": "_3d4d27ecb82517dd8b071e78617138d880ba4e5be3",
  "nameID": "_105a83da92adc02458006be4b024a8f3fba35d71de",
  "nameIDFormat": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient",
  "spNameQualifier": "http://app.example.com",
  "uid": "1",
  "eduPersonAffiliation": "group1",
  "email": "user1@example.com",
  "attributes": {
    "uid": "1",
    "eduPersonAffiliation": "group1",
    "email": "user1@example.com"
  }
}

*/

// about logout...because single logout was not implemented
// in this example you must clear your browser state in order
// to be able to test login procedure again OR restart test
// IdP container and test application so that both forgets
// open single sign in session

If you are new to SAML consider reading through these:

Assertions and Protocols for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0 OASIS Standard, 15 March 2005 https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf
Profiles for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0 OASIS Standard, 15 March 2005 https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf
Security and Privacy Considerations for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0 OASIS Standard, 15 March 2005 https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-sec-consider-2.0-os.pdf
Metadata for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) 2.0 OASIS Standard, 15 March 2005 https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf
and this: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SAML_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html

